# SQL Server - Create a New ID "group by column"

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

**Order**

```
OrderID INT
...
```

**OrderItems**

```
OrderIemID INT
OrderID INT
ItemNO INT
```

What I want is `ItemNO` starts at 1 for each `OrderID` and increases by 1 for each new `OrderIemID` in `OrderItems`.

I added this into the insert trigger. But is it possible to do this in a different way? UDF and calculate column, and use persistent?

---

### UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[afnc_Proc_CreateNewOrderItemsItemNo] (
 @OrderID INT
) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NewItemNo INT 

    SET @NewItemNo=1

    SELECT TOP 1 @NewItemNo = ItemNo + 1
        FROM dbo.atbl_Proc_OrderItems
        WHERE OrderID=@OrderID
         ORDER BY ItemNo DESC

    RETURN @NewItemNo
END
```

---

### Trigger:

```
 UPDATE U   
    SET ItemNO=dbo.afnc_Proc_CreateNewOrderItemsItemNo(I.OrderID)
    FROM atbl_Proc_OrderItems AS U
    INNER JOIN inserted I ON U.PrimKey=I.PrimKey
```

Comment: If `ItemNo` 1 for a particular `OrderID` is deleted, should all other items be renumbered? If not, should a deleted ItemNo be reused when a new item is added?

Comment: Why do you need to store this information in the table when you can always derive it quite easily at query time? Storing redundant information is wasteful and can lead to unnecessary maintenance.

Comment: Also, how do you define "new"? Can you show the code that your trigger uses? If there is no way in the table to determine what order the order items were added in, then the numbering will be arbitrary. If OrderItemID is an IDENTITY column, then you already know the order (my answer assumes that OrderItemID is an IDENTITY column, or that the "order" can be defined by this column).

Comment: It sounds like you have a working solution but you're not happy with it? If so, what exactly is the problem with your current implementation? You should also explain something about the ordering of item numbers and how to handle additions/deletions. Is it important to keep the item numbers consistent, e.g. for invoicing?

Comment: If you delete an OrderItemID will otherwise ItemNO lose one, if you do not save the value. UPDATE: I Will add the code I use today.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT OrderID, OrderItemID, ItemNo,
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderItemID)
  FROM dbo.OrderItems
)
UPDATE x SET ItemNo = rn;
```

However as I mentioned in a comment this operation is quite wasteful, since you can simply use this `ROW_NUMBER()` operation at query time and it is guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: This is exactly what I would suggest